# SO - Multiple people editing at the same time? Have to abandon edit?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, edits

It has happened to me twice that I get the opportunity to edit a question on Stack-Overflow, but that when trying to submit my edit, I get a dialog informing me that another edit has already been submitted, and that I cannot submit my new edit.

I can then not submit my edit, and have to abandon my edited version.

This is a bit frustrating when you take a couple of minutes to do a good edit, and then have to abandon it, not being able to add it.

Is this a bug? I thought that picking a question from the review queue "locks" it for me to edit?

Comment: I don't know if there is a lock in the review queue, but you can also edit the question / answer when you are viewing it directly. I do this often if I see things that need to be fixed.

Comment: There is a lock. Unfortunately, it's an optimistic lock, i.e. "let's hope nobody else edits".

Comment: Might be nice if stack exchange guessed a merge between the two (subversion style) and asked you to approve the merge

Comment: That's the good side of the coin. With less than 2K if you submit your edit suggestion and 2K+ user submit his own edit *afterwards*, your suggestion is getting kicked out and auto rejected - and you'll never know unless checking it manually.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug. Anyone can view the question outside review queues and for most of the review queues, you're not the only one who gets the question. If your edit is substantial enough, you should still be able to override the other edit. If it doesn't allow you to do that and you think your edit is better, you could simply copy your edit and edit again.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can "copy", reload, and then edit... but that defeats the purpose as I will be overwriting a now new edited version, which I did not include in my own edit. I understand why it does what it does, but was curious as to if its a bug, or if its be design.